# Parsing non-standard XML (CDATA tag)

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

When I want to parsing XML document in Python using BeautifulSoup library, 
I faced some problems. The XML document that I want to parse:

```
<item>
<title><![CDATA[Title Sample]]></title>
<link /><![CDATA[http://banhada.kr/?cateCode=09&viewCode=S0941580]]>
<time_start>2011-10-10 09:00:00</time_start>
<time_end>2011-10-17 09:00:00</time_end>
<price_original>35000</price_original>
<price_now>20000</price_now>
</item>
```

As you can see above,  tag is a little strange. In my opinion, that( tag) is not a stand XML form, right? How can I parse this terrible form?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need BeautifulStoneSoup or lxml. Python's included batteries do the job just fine, and there doesn't seem to be anything non-compliant about your XML.

```
>>> content='''\
... <item>
... <title><![CDATA[Title Sample]]></title>
... <link /><![CDATA[http://banhada.kr/?cateCode=09&viewCode=S0941580]]>
... <time_start>2011-10-10 09:00:00</time_start>
... <time_end>2011-10-17 09:00:00</time_end>
... <price_original>35000</price_original>
... <price_now>20000</price_now>
... </item>'''
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
>>> foo = et.XML(content)
>>> for e in foo:
...     print e.tag, e.text, repr(e.tail)
...
title Title Sample '\n'
link None 'http://banhada.kr/?cateCode=09&viewCode=S0941580\n'
time_start 2011-10-10 09:00:00 '\n'
time_end 2011-10-17 09:00:00 '\n'
price_original 35000 '\n'
price_now 20000 '\n'
>>>
```

Comment: this worked for me on XML that BeautifulSoup couldn't handle!

Answer (score 7):

You could use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing%20XML) to parse XML:

```
import bs4 as bs
content='''\
<item>
<title><![CDATA[Title Sample]]></title>
<link /><![CDATA[http://banhada.kr/?cateCode=09&viewCode=S0941580]]>
<time_start>2011-10-10 09:00:00</time_start>
<time_end>2011-10-17 09:00:00</time_end>
<price_original>35000</price_original>
<price_now>20000</price_now>
</item>'''    

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content, 'xml')

title = soup.title
print(title.string)
# Title Sample

link = soup.link.nextSibling
print(link)
# http://banhada.kr/?cateCode=09&viewCode=S0941580
```

Under the hood, BeautifulSoup uses [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) for parsing XML.
Although it's not needed here, you might want to use lxml directly, since it gives you more succinct ways to navigate through XML using XPath:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

content='''\
<item>
<title><![CDATA[Title Sample]]></title>
<link /><![CDATA[http://banhada.kr/?cateCode=09&viewCode=S0941580]]>
<time_start>2011-10-10 09:00:00</time_start>
<time_end>2011-10-17 09:00:00</time_end>
<price_original>35000</price_original>
<price_now>20000</price_now>
</item>'''    

doc = ET.fromstring(content)

title = doc.find('title')
print(title.text)
# Title Sample

link = doc.find('link')
print(link.tail)
# http://banhada.kr/?cateCode=09&viewCode=S0941580
```

Comment: UserWarning: The BeautifulStoneSoup class is deprecated. Instead of using it, pass features="xml" into the BeautifulSoup constructor.

Comment: Updated my answer to use BeautifulSoup4.