# Is it possible to return to print line I've already left?

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I am currently trying to write a function to parse an xml file. But I've run into trouble and I'm wondering if it's possible to return to a print line that I've already left.

Say I have the string "Christ is my rock", is it possible to make an output like below

```
Crsimrc
hitsyok
```

Perhaps I may have to approach my problem another way but in the mean time I was wondering if something like this is actually possible.

Comment: Why not assemble a string which contains a newline character and then print the fully assembled string?

Comment: I've tried that right now. thing is, python will continue on the last line I just left. I've even dabbled into numpy array to order the strings but it's not gonna work....I think someday such a thing may be possible, but for now it's outta reach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but if your goal is to print some sort of report, a natural approach is to just use a list of strings, with 1 string per line. If the list of strings is called `lines` then instead of `print(s)` use `lines.append(s)` (or `lines.append(str(s))` if `s` isn't already a string. When done, join on `'\n'`.

```
>>> lines = []
>>> lines.append('cat')
>>> lines.append('dog')
>>> print(''.join(lines))
catdog
```

You can modify earlier strings, e.g. append to the end of them. For example,
if you want to split the characters into different lines, do something like:

```
>>> lines = ['','']
>>> s = 'this is a test'
>>> for i,c in enumerate(s):
    lines[i%2] += c


>>> print('\n'.join(lines))
ti sats
hsi  et
```

Since strings are immutable, if you are going to make numerous changes to individual characters of previous lines, this approach of having a list of strings might be inefficient. A modification of the idea would be to have `lines` be a list of lists, where each of the inner lists is a list of one-character strings. The net result would be a jagged array of characters. `print(s)` would be replaced by

```
lines.append(list(s))
```

and when you have what you want you could print it all via:

```
print('\n'.join(''.join(line) for line in lines))
```

If for some reason you don't want to wait until your lines are fully assembled before printing them but instead want to see previous lines being actively modified, consider using a GUI solution such as `Tkinter` with its `text box` widget.

Comment: Thanks John...Does exactly what I have in mind. But it's not sufficient for what I'm trying to achieve...So I start looking at `tkinter` at your suggestion. Here is what I want to achieve. Let's say I have printed lines 1 to 5. Now I'm on line 6, but I want to go back to line 2 and add something in front of it, and maybe something in front of line 4 also, then come back where I left off. Will I be able to achieve this using a GUI like you suggested??

Comment: I think that a list of lines is probably the best approach. You can maintain a variable for the current line number to keep track of where you left off, and also modify previous lines any way you want: `lines[2] = s + lines[2]` (but list indices start at 0). You can also delete or insert whole lines. The only advantage of `tkinter` would be able to see it in action, but at the cost of much more code. In parsing an `xml` file -- just display the final string. Speaking of `xml`: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7785831/4996248 . Other modules can also be used for `xml` parsing.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working with bs4 right now. Far better solution.